# Reusing SVG definitions

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to display the same SVG potentially hundreds of times in an HTML table.
The table is created entirely using javascript including the SVG defs.

My question is, it it more efficient to create a new SVG element each time, or should I create the SVG element once and clone it into an HTML Image using XML Serializer and then reuse the image (i.e. creating an HTML Image element and setting the src to that cloned SVG)?

Comment: IMM it would be about the same: svg/image are documents too, but they are inaccessible. You may also consider [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) element, which may make you write less code, even though it will still be the same for browsers.

Comment: Thanks Kalido. I decided against using "use" in the SVG definitions (which I agree would have been cleaner) because I also want to display the same SVG images multiple times on a HTML canvas later and I know that I will have to clone the svg definition into an Image to do that (and that external svg references will not work when doing this).

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not done any exact timing, there appear to be no speed concerns at all in creating hundreds of SVGs and setting them all to the same internal definition.